# Fast internet, but slow local area network speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, internet

Essentially I'm trying to get better Virtual Desktop bitrate performance on my Meta Quest 3, which uses local area network speed. But no matter what I try, my local area network speeds never exceed 150 Mbps (15MB/s) even though my 5GHz network is rated at 1200Mbps. I can only set the bitrate of Virtual Desktop up to 90Mbps before games start jittering and latency spikes.

PC Ethernet link speed is 1Gbps. I tested a local file transfer from my laptop to to my desktop PC and that's also throttled to no greater than 150Mbps. I do an Ookla test and Google internet speed test from both computers and they easily get up to 300Mbps. I also see YouTube reviewers who say they can do 200Mbps or better in VD just fine with no problems. Here's my setup:

**Wi-Fi router:** Netgear Nighthawk RAX10 (AX1800)
PC specs: Intel Gigabit Ethernet port hardwired into the first port of the router with a Cat6 Cable. (Internet speed test shows 300Mbps easily).

**GPU** 2080 Ti

**CPU** 5800x 8-core

**Motherboard** X570 AORUS ELITE

**32GB RAM**

I went as far as scanning WiFi signals around me and setting my 5GHz network to a channel separate from other networks around me (I live in a suburb with not a lot of WiFi channels around me). Enabled OFDMA which didn't make a difference. I've checked RouterLogin.net settings and can't see anything that would be throttling local area connection. Checked Ethernet adapter and enabled Full Duplex at 1 Gigabits.

I'm just at a loss on how to speed up my local area network to get smoother wireless VR gaming experience. I'm starting to suspect maybe my Graphics card has something to do with it since VD encodes and decodes the VR stream this way, but the fact that local area network file sharing tops out at 150Mbps and my GPU usage is nowhere near 100% leads me to believe my router is throttling my Local Area Network performance. I'm the only one on the 5GHz network with my Quest 3 and Phone connected to it.

Comment: My answer got deleted, even though I think it was valid - Using a dedicated VR bridge seems to work a lot better than a proper router (no matter how fast), though I'm not aware of why.  If you were willing to buy a custom thing to solve it, I've had good results with it.